# Get day,month and day of sqlite

Tags: sqlite

When I want to get the date without the time I use

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) from nameTable
```

I always get this result: -471-11-24

Comment: You have to call `strftime()` or `date()` on the result of your query, not while trying to query.

Comment: Even if you use it in the where, all rows are queried, for example: SELECT name from nameTable WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date)=strftime('%Y-%m-%d',:date)

Comment: what result did you expect ? what is the value of the date column ? I'm guessing it is interpreted as a julian date

Comment: Yes, because it is still in the query. What columns does `nameTable` have? `name` and `date`? Do you want to get the date of one entry or of multiple entries?

Comment: No, it does not interpret it as a julian. And date column is date type. And I get it from one object.I expect to get rows that are similar to date.

Comment: SQLite has no date storage type. Dates are usually stored as ISO formatted, Julian days or Unix seconds. Do you have an example of an actual value in the database (i.e. without strftime) ?

Comment: The column `date` must contain values in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Does it?

Comment: Not necessarily, it is up to the application. `strftime()` can handle 3 formats (Unix seconds needs an additional 'unixepoch' modifier)

Comment: Actual value in the database is 1593742280658

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***

> Actual value in the database is 1593742280658

That appears to be [Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) ***in milliseconds*** which SQLite cannot handle. You need to turn it into seconds, and then tell `strftime` you want unix epoch time with the `unixepoch` modifier.

```
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 1593742280658/1000, 'unixepoch');
strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 1593742280658/1000, 'unixepoch')
-----------------------------------------------------
2020-07-03
```

Why `-471-11-24`? That's what you get from `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 0);`. Without the `unixepoch` modifier, SQLite interprets an integer as a [Julian day number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), the number of days since November 24, 4714 BC.

You get -471, not -4714, because `%Y` only has space for four characters. `select date(0)` will give the full `-4713-11-24`.

With `select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 1593742280658)` SQLite is attempting to interpret 1593742280658 as Julian days. This is well outside its defined range so anything can happen.

> These functions only work for dates between 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and 9999-12-31 23:59:59 (julian day numbers 1721059.5 through 5373484.5). For dates outside that range, the results of these functions are undefined.

In my implementation, I get an empty string. In yours it seems you get Julian day 0.

---

> And date column is date type

SQLite has [no real date type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype).

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

And unlike other SQL databases, SQLite types are determined by the value. It will ignore your type declaration.

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

If you put `42` into `nameTable.date` it will be stored as an integer. If you put `'fourty-two'` into `nameTable.date` it will be stored as text.

Comment: Actual value in the database is 1593742280658

Comment: @محمديحيىالفقيه That appears to be epoch time in *milliseconds*. I will update the answer.

Comment: Nice job, I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `strftime()` to format the date.
The function `date()` with the modifier `'unixepoch'` will return the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
select date(date / 1000, 'unixepoch') from tablename
```

You must divide by 1000 to remove the milliseconds.
For example for a value like:

```
1593742280658
```

for the date in your table, the result will be

```
'2020-07-03'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7TuLxUC1DJ4o8wPVEMu7YR/1).